# nginx location redirect all but specific domain with any subdomain and any path

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect

I am trying to do a redirect using location regex.I want everything to be redirected to 404 exept from the examplesite.com with every possible path and subdomain.examplesite.com should be redirected to my server.

```
examplesite.com redirect
https://m.examplesite.com redirect
www.examplesite.com/something redirect
everything else redirect to 404
```

This is my config:

```
location ~ ^(?!(.?)examplesite.com/?(.*)) {
return 404;
}

location / {
return 302 $scheme://192.168.1.1/index.html; #this is a local web server
}
```

which must be wrong because it redirects every examplesite.com i tried to 404.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this ^((?!examplesite.com).)*$ - Any url which does not have examplesite.com can be redirected to 404 and If the URL has examplesite.com in it then regardless of its position then it wont match.

Comment: That didn't seem to work so I went back to using dnsmasq to achieve this.
I tried both location ~* ^((?!examplesite.com).)*$ and location ^((?!examplesite.com).)*$

Comment: Strange. I tested this regex pattern myself and it worked fine locally and also in online regex pattern matcher.

Comment: I tried it all again.It doesn't work in nginx and I also tested the first 3 online regex testers and it doesn't match there either.

My configuration is like this:
location ^((?!examplesite.com).)*$ {
return 404;
}

location / {

I also tried removing the 'everything else' location and leave your suggestion plus this:
location ^((?examplesite.com).)*$ 

and it doesnt work either.I do no dns redirects and changing the configuration to something else is working, but not what I want unless I do it via dnsmasq.

Comment: This is probably my mistake since I am getting strange results.http sites get redirected to local server while https sites all get the same response, which is a certification error.I don't know if you can get this both from redirection and 404 redirection, so I can't test it.
You are right about the regex, on the nginx tester site it works as expected.I tried to upvote but I don't have enough points yet.